# Python Incremental Day/Time Schedule

Tags: python, time, schedule

I have a script that schedules based on Day and time. A sample of this is below:

```
schedule_time = ['06:00','06:30','07:00','07:30','08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30']
schedule_day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Ralph', 'Joe']
```

I have an issue creating a schedule. With my current code, i get an output of day/time for each name:

```
for day in schedule_day:
    for time in schedule_time:
        for name in names:
            print day, time, name
```

the output I receive is:

```
Monday 06:00 John
Monday 06:00 Sam
Monday 06:00 Ralph
Monday 06:00 Joe
Monday 06:30 John
Monday 06:30 Sam
Monday 06:30 Ralph
Monday 06:30 Joe
Monday 07:00 John
Monday 07:00 Sam
Monday 07:00 Ralph
Monday 07:00 Joe
Monday 07:30 John
Monday 07:30 Sam
```

The name list can grow or shrink based on need. I am looking to schedule a name to a day and time. If there are only 3 names, then I would expect the following:

```
Monday 06:00 John
Monday 06:30 Sam
Monday 07:00 Ralph
```

If there were more, I would expect the following output:

```
Monday 06:00 Name1
Monday 06:30 Name2
Monday 07:00 Name3
Monday 07:30 Name4
Monday 08:00 Name5
Monday 08:30 Name6
Monday 09:00 Name7
Monday 09:30 Name8
Monday 10:00 Name9
Monday 10:30 Name10
```

If there were more names than day and time slots i would like the output to loop back to Monday for the 'next' week. 
I have tried loops, dictionaries and an not familiar with all the tools to use for this issue.

Comment: Hmm, i must be new at this python gig; I'm not sure this is a *great* question, but I also don't see what's so terrible that it deserves so many downvotes (even in its state before the edits)

Comment: Why have you removed your code so far? This question needed, if anything, **more**; the output your current code gave compared to what you wanted would have been helpful.

Comment: I am trying to better my question to limit down votes so I can continue to use Stack Overflow to learn

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I was editing the question to try to get a format that would see less down votes so i could continue to use the community.

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work, provide a minimal example (see e.g. http://sscce.org) and the full error traceback or the inputs and expected and actual outputs. If you want tips on writing good questions, see the Help Center; there's plenty there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip, product

for timeslot, name in izip(cycle(product(schedule_day, 
                                         schedule_time)),
                           names):
    print name, timeslot
```

Here [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is used to create the appropriate day-time pairs, then [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat that as long as there are names, then [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to pair the timeslots up with the names.